# text change event sj:autocompleter struts2 jquery

Tags: struts2, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, struts2-jquery

Here is what I am trying to do.
If the user makes a selection from the suggested options then I display a div tag using jquery. I use onCompleteTopics to fire this event.

Now when the user makes any changes to the text box I want to hide the div tag again unless the user makes a selection from the suggested options.

How to fire the text changed event on jquery struts2 autocompleter.

I make a div tag visible when the user selects something from the suggestions using **onCompleteTopics**.

However if the user changes the text in the field I want to hide the div tag again.

But I am not able to find the right event for the same.

Comment: Does onChangeTopics work ?

Comment: Examine generated html, find input field for autocompleter, select this field in js and bind change event.

Comment: @AleksandrM new to jquery. some example please

Comment: @AndreaLigios onChangeTopics works but onCompleteTopics is called after that even if no selection was made hence defeating the purpose

Comment: Then use onChangeTopics and not onCompleteTopics ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios I'll try that in a bit. I've also edited the question to explain what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a lot of permutation and combination I managed to figure out the solution. Its not straightforward maybe not the ideal solution but it works.

Struts Code

```
<sj:autocompleter
                    theme="simple" name="userName" id="idautocomplete"
                    href="%{fetchList}" onSelectTopics="complete" onSearchTopics="textchange" 
                    loadOnTextChange="true" loadMinimumCount="3" />
```

Note I have used onSelectTopics and onSearchTopics but this itself do not solve the problem. I have to use some jquery along with this.

jquery

```
    var gvar;
$.subscribe("complete", function(event, data) {
    gvar = data;
    setTimeout(delayfunc, 0);
});

$.subscribe("textchange", function(event, data) {       
    $('#idBizAccess').css("display","none");
});

function delayfunc() {      
    $('#idBizAccess').css("display","table-row");
}
```

The unusual part here is setTimeout with delay 0. I tried calling the function directly but it doesn't fetch the selected value instead it just fetches the value that is typed in the autocompleter field.
Now it works as per the requirement.